# Link selective rows from one sheet to the next

Tags: excel

So I've searched everywhere... I have an office 2007 excel spreadsheet with two pages, one labeled "i" and the other "t." I need to display selective rows (those rows that have a value in column A--not all do) from "i" in "t." I also need the rows in the "t" page to be in numerical order. I figured out how to do it across all rows, but not how to selectively add rows with values only in column A. Further, when I add new rows to "i," "t" doesn't automatically update. Any advice on how to accomplish this would be of immense help!

I have access to office 2010. I don't know if that makes the coding easier?

Thank you!

Jason

Answer (score 0):

You could try a user-defined function like this:

```
Function NonBlank(Selection As Range, Index As Integer) As Variant
    Dim Count As Integer
    Count = 0
    For Each cell In Selection
        If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then Count = Count + 1
        If Index = Count Then
            NonBlank = cell.Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Then on Sheet t, you can put =NonBlank(i!A:A,ROW(A1)) in the first cell where you want the first non-blank value of Sheet i, and then copy the formulas down.